# Initialize custom UIView before drawRect gets called

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to customize a UIView by calling its drawRect method, so I subclass UIView and name it MyView. The drawing will depend on some variable(myString in this example), so I need to initialize the variable before drawRect starts. My MyView.h looks like

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;
@end
```

In the viewController.m, if I do the following

```
MyView *myView = [MyView alloc] initWithFrame:someRect];
[myView setMyString:@"string value"];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

everything works as expected, the myString is set before drawRect get called.

The problem I am trying to solve is if I want to add the MyView to the view controller by using Interface Builder(drag and drop an UIView to the view controller's view and change its class to MyView), where is the point that I can set myString before drawRect gets called?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if drawrect is called before setting the variable.  You can call `[view setNeedsDisplay]` after you set the variable and it will redraw accordingly.  IF this is done in something like `viewDidLoad` then the user will never see the improperly drawn view, but will see it after redrawing the correct way.

Comment: The answer by Armand DOHM works for me, thank you.

Comment: You notice that my comment was a few minutes before his answer?  I'm glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it in your view controller

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    MyView *myView = self.view;
   [myView setMyString:@"string value"];
 ]
```

Comment: I think this line `MyView *myView = self.view;` will not work for my scenario since I put MyView on top of the view of the view controller (in Interface Builder). But I did try `[self.myView setMyString:@"string value"];`, drawRect still runs first before the value is set.

Comment: Update: yes, it works. I put the NSLog in the wrong place before. Thank you for the answer.